# Numerical issues in R

Tags: r, floating-point, comparison-operators

It is a well known fact that when comparing two real numbers it is always better to work with a small tolerance to avoid numerical issues.

I am looking for an example where when we compare a number `x` having `d` number of decimal places returns `FALSE` for the below expression:

```
round(x, d) == x
```

For example if `x=0.1234` then `d=4`. However, this is not a good example as when you evaluate `round(x, d) == x` returns `TRUE`. I am looking for a value of `x` where `round(x, d) == x` turns to be `FALSE`.

Comment: not sure what you mean. `round(1.1234, 2) == 1.1234` returns `FALSE`

Comment: @Ronak I saw in a R code that it uses `abs(x - round(x, d)) < eps`. So thinking of a case where `x == round(x, d)` would fail.

Comment: @RonakShah He/she means `round(x,d)` where `d` is the number of digits after the dot. `round(1.1234, d) == 1.1234` returns `TRUE` for `d=4`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I see. Thanks. I am not sure why would it fail though.

Comment: @RonakShah It would only fail if you input a number that can't be represented exactly (difficult to do) or if you calculate such a number (rather easy).

Comment: @RonakShah In your answer the last iteration turns to be `FALSE`. So it is a one rare case where `x == round(x, d)` failed.

Comment: @RonakShah Is there any particular reason to hold this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's unclear how you define `d`. Here I assume it's defined based on exact algebra.

```
for (i in 1:20) print(1/(8 * 10^i) == round(1/(8 * 10^i), 3 + i))
sprintf("%.50f", 1/8e20)
#[1] "0.00000000000000000000124999999999999993158684291616"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. A case where this comparison breakdown.